# how to extract info from JSON, create a dynamic column and then store info from the JSON into that column using postgresSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql

I need some help creating an sql query. I have table (lets call it 'x') which has a column called response_json that stores json objects.

What I would like to do is, in each json object, I would like to extract distinct 'internalID' and the 'entryDate'. I would like the 'entryDate' as a column.

I would then like to go through each json object again and store the 'NetAmount' for that particular 'entryDate' and 'internalID'. Hence my table would look like:

| internalID | 2021-02-05 | 2021-02-18 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 338497 | 102.78 | -430.0 |
| 33111 | -1021.43 | -15 |

Sample Json:

```
{
  "ResponseData": {
    "ToDate": "2023-01-09T00:00:00",
    "FromDate": "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
    "InternalID": 338497,
    "Transactions": [
      {
        "Asset": "WPL",
        "Broker": "",
        "BuyBack": "0",
        "Quantity": 4.0,
        "EntryDate": "2021-02-05T16:36:40.597Z",
        "Narration": "",
        "NetAmount": 102.78,
        "Unconfirmed": "0",
        "AveragePrice": 25.7,
        "BrokerageGST": 0.08,
        "DeemedAmount": 0.0,
        "ExchangeCode": "ASX",
        "GSTClaimable": 0.0,
        "AmendmentDate": "2021-02-05T16:36:40.597Z",
        "TransactionId": 1646197085,
        "DisposalMethod": "",
        "SettlementDate": "2021-02-09T00:00:00Z",
        "TradedCurrency": "AUD",
        "BrokerageIncGST": 0.79,
        "ContractNoteRef": "1415949038",
        "CostBaseUnknown": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "2021-02-05T00:00:00Z",
        "TransactionType": "Buy",
        "AssetDescription": "WOODSIDE PETROLEUM LTD FPO",
        "SettlementCurrency": "AUD",
        "TradedCurrencyAmount": 102.78,
        "SettlementCurrencyAmount": 102.78,
        "TradedCurrencyAveragePrice": 25.7,
        "SettlementCurrencyAveragePrice": 25.7
      },
      {
        "Asset": "FMG",
        "Broker": "",
        "BuyBack": "0",
        "Quantity": -44.0,
        "EntryDate": "2021-02-05T16:36:40.597Z",
        "Narration": "",
        "NetAmount": -1021.43,
        "Unconfirmed": "0",
        "AveragePrice": 23.21,
        "BrokerageGST": 0.13,
        "DeemedAmount": 0.0,
        "ExchangeCode": "ASX",
        "GSTClaimable": 0.0,
        "AmendmentDate": "2021-02-05T18:43:00.437Z",
        "TransactionId": 1646198826,
        "DisposalMethod": "Minimise",
        "SettlementDate": "2021-02-09T00:00:00Z",
        "TradedCurrency": "AUD",
        "BrokerageIncGST": 1.29,
        "ContractNoteRef": "1415949044",
        "CostBaseUnknown": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "2021-02-05T00:00:00Z",
        "TransactionType": "Sell",
        "AssetDescription": "FORTESCUE METALS GROUP LTD FPO",
        "SettlementCurrency": "AUD",
        "TradedCurrencyAmount": 1021.43,
        "SettlementCurrencyAmount": 1021.43,
        "TradedCurrencyAveragePrice": 23.21,
        "SettlementCurrencyAveragePrice": 23.21
      },
      {
        "Asset": "CPU",
        "Broker": "",
        "BuyBack": "0",
        "Quantity": -31.0,
        "EntryDate": "2021-02-18T16:57:46.69Z",
        "Narration": "",
        "NetAmount": -430.0,
        "Unconfirmed": "0",
        "AveragePrice": 13.87,
        "BrokerageGST": 0.1,
        "DeemedAmount": 0.0,
        "ExchangeCode": "ASX",
        "GSTClaimable": 0.0,
        "AmendmentDate": "2021-02-18T21:47:25.733Z",
        "TransactionId": 1648252938,
        "DisposalMethod": "Minimise",
        "SettlementDate": "2021-02-22T00:00:00Z",
        "TradedCurrency": "AUD",
        "BrokerageIncGST": 0.99,
        "ContractNoteRef": "1423259742",
        "CostBaseUnknown": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "2021-02-18T00:00:00Z",
        "TransactionType": "Sell",
        "AssetDescription": "COMPUTERSHARE LIMITED. FPO",
        "SettlementCurrency": "AUD",
        "TradedCurrencyAmount": 430.0,
        "SettlementCurrencyAmount": 430.0,
        "TradedCurrencyAveragePrice": 13.87,
        "SettlementCurrencyAveragePrice": 13.87
```

I tried using jsonb_array_elements(response_json) but I get an error 'cannot extract elements from an object'

Thank you for any help or hints!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think that you need to split the json → update data → group the json again. So I suggest as below:

```
WITH t as (select '{
  "ResponseData": {
    "ToDate": "2023-01-09T00:00:00",
    "FromDate": "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
    "InternalID": 338497,
    "Transactions": [
      {
        "Asset": "WPL",
        "Broker": "",
        "BuyBack": "0",
        "Quantity": 4.0,
        "EntryDate": "2021-02-05T16:36:40.597Z",
        "Narration": "",
        "NetAmount": 102.78,
        "Unconfirmed": "0",
        "AveragePrice": 25.7,
        "BrokerageGST": 0.08,
        "DeemedAmount": 0.0,
        "ExchangeCode": "ASX",
        "GSTClaimable": 0.0,
        "AmendmentDate": "2021-02-05T16:36:40.597Z",
        "TransactionId": 1646197085,
        "DisposalMethod": "",
        "SettlementDate": "2021-02-09T00:00:00Z",
        "TradedCurrency": "AUD",
        "BrokerageIncGST": 0.79,
        "ContractNoteRef": "1415949038",
        "CostBaseUnknown": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "2021-02-05T00:00:00Z",
        "TransactionType": "Buy",
        "AssetDescription": "WOODSIDE PETROLEUM LTD FPO",
        "SettlementCurrency": "AUD",
        "TradedCurrencyAmount": 102.78,
        "SettlementCurrencyAmount": 102.78,
        "TradedCurrencyAveragePrice": 25.7,
        "SettlementCurrencyAveragePrice": 25.7
      },
      {
        "Asset": "FMG",
        "Broker": "",
        "BuyBack": "0",
        "Quantity": -44.0,
        "EntryDate": "2021-02-05T16:36:40.597Z",
        "Narration": "",
        "NetAmount": -1021.43,
        "Unconfirmed": "0",
        "AveragePrice": 23.21,
        "BrokerageGST": 0.13,
        "DeemedAmount": 0.0,
        "ExchangeCode": "ASX",
        "GSTClaimable": 0.0,
        "AmendmentDate": "2021-02-05T18:43:00.437Z",
        "TransactionId": 1646198826,
        "DisposalMethod": "Minimise",
        "SettlementDate": "2021-02-09T00:00:00Z",
        "TradedCurrency": "AUD",
        "BrokerageIncGST": 1.29,
        "ContractNoteRef": "1415949044",
        "CostBaseUnknown": "0",
        "TransactionDate": "2021-02-05T00:00:00Z",
        "TransactionType": "Sell",
        "AssetDescription": "FORTESCUE METALS GROUP LTD FPO",
        "SettlementCurrency": "AUD",
        "TradedCurrencyAmount": 1021.43,
        "SettlementCurrencyAmount": 1021.43,
        "TradedCurrencyAveragePrice": 23.21,
        "SettlementCurrencyAveragePrice": 23.21
      }]}}'::jsonb a),
    t2 AS (
            SELECT 
                jsonb_extract_path(a,'ResponseData','ToDate') AS "ToDate",
                jsonb_extract_path(a,'ResponseData','FromDate') AS "FromDate",
                jsonb_extract_path(a,'ResponseData','InternalID') AS "InternalID",
                jsonb_extract_path(a,'ResponseData','Transactions') as "Transactions"
            FROM t
        ), -- Split Array 
    t3 AS (SELECT json_data || '{"NetAmount": 9999999999}'::jsonb as json_neu FROM t2, jsonb_array_elements("Transactions") a(json_data)), -- Update Data
    t4 AS (SELECT jsonb_agg(json_neu) AS "Transactions" FROM t3), -- group json data
    t5 AS (SELECT t2."ToDate", "FromDate", "InternalID", t4."Transactions" FROM t4, t2), -- build ResponseData
    t6 AS (SELECT row_to_json(t5) AS "ResponseData" FROM t5) -- Last ResponseData
SELECT row_to_json(t6) as final_result
FROM t6
```

Hopefully it will meet your requirement.